# How to put the value of :face into a variable/list/hash in emacs lisp?

Tags: emacs, backquote

I am sorry I am not familiar with emacs-lisp.

I wrote a config file as follows, but it did not work correctly.

So how could I put the value of `:face` in `svg-tag-tags` into a variable (here is `todo-faces-a`)?

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
   '(todo-faces-a '(:background "red"  :distant-foreground "red"  :foreground  "white"   :height 0.7  :weight bold) )
   )

(setq svg-tag-tags
      `(
    ;; TODO / DONE
    ("TODO" . ((lambda (tag) (svg-tag-make "TODO" :face 'todo-faces-a
                           :inverse nil :margin 0 :padding 0 :ascent 0 :height 0 ))))
))
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this emacs.SE question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7481/). It might also be a dup of a question here, in which case it should be deleted. Hopefully someone will look for that dup. ;-)

Comment: The answer is to tell Lisp to *evaluate* the subexpression `(svg-tag-make...)` and insert the result in the backquoted sexp. You do that with `,` (or `,@`, depending on whether you want splicing).

Comment: Finallly, I use `  (defface todo-faces-a '((t :foreground "black"  :background "gray95"      :box "gray90"  )) "Face for default tag" :group nil)` , it seems work. But I still do not know what type of `todo-faces-a`...

Answer (score 0):

defface doesn't create the variable todo-faces-a.
Instead, it adds a property named face-defface-spec to the property list of 'todo-faces-a:

```
(get 'todo-faces-a 'face-defface-spec)
    => ((t :foreground "black" :background "gray95" :box "gray90"))
```

So in order to access it in a backquoted form, this should do:

```
(setq svg-tag-tags
    `(.... ,(cdar (get 'todo-faces-a 'face-defface-spec)) ...)
```

Where

```
(cdar (get 'todo-faces-a 'face-defface-spec))
```

evaluates to

```
(:foreground "black" :background "gray95" :box "gray90")
```